# Jasper Report Error retrieving field value from bean when generating Report with JSON file

Tags: java, json, jasper-reports

I reconnect with you. Since the last few times you have helped me and I have been with this problem for some time now and to solve it, my job depends because I am in practice and I have to solve it.

Mi JSON:

```js
[
  {
    "fecha": "03/07/2018 08:16:58",
    "velocidad_up": "30",
    "velocidad_dw": "30",
    "ppoe_usuario": "48575443596ACB9B",
    "ppoe_password": "48575443596ACB9B",
    "c": "0"
  },
  {
    "fecha": "03/07/2018 08:23:13",
    "velocidad_up": "30",
    "velocidad_dw": "30",
    "ppoe_usuario": "4857544321F99C9B",
    "ppoe_password": "4857544321F99C9B",
    "c": "0"
  },
  {
    "fecha": "04/07/2018 18:58:02",
    "velocidad_up": "5",
    "velocidad_dw": "20",
    "ppoe_usuario": "48575443DC26FB9B",
    "ppoe_password": "48575443DC26FB9B",
    "c": "0"
  },
  {
    "fecha": "05/07/2018 08:33:00",
    "velocidad_up": "10",
    "velocidad_dw": "20",
    "ppoe_usuario": "48575443DC23E79B",
    "ppoe_password": "48575443DC23E79B",
    "c": "0"
  },
  {
    "fecha": "06/07/2018 18:50:29",
    "velocidad_up": "5",
    "velocidad_dw": "20",
    "ppoe_usuario": "48575443A351D79B",
    "ppoe_password": "48575443A351D79B",
    "c": "0"
  },
  {
    "fecha": "06/07/2018 18:53:13",
    "velocidad_up": "5",
    "velocidad_dw": "25",
    "ppoe_usuario": "48575443DC26A59B",
    "ppoe_password": "48575443DC26A59B",
    "c": "0"
  }
]
```

The fact is that when trying to generate a report in JASPER REPORT with dynamic columns from a JSON file, when arriving at the line where Jasper print is generated, the following error appears:

```css
Exception in thread "main" net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error retrieving field value from bean: fecha.
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getBeanProperty(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:193)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getFieldValue(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:158)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource.getFieldValue(JRBeanCollectionDataSource.java:104)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.setOldValues(JRFillDataset.java:1489)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:1390)
```

This error occurs on the line:

```js
jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parametros, dataSource);
```

But in reality it is seen that NETBEANS gives a warning on the lines:

```js
public static JRDataSource getDatasource(List<AbstractColumn> columns) throws FileNotFoundException {
      
         Gson gson = new Gson();
         JsonElement json = gson.fromJson(new FileReader("C:/tools/2datos-prue.json"), JsonElement.class);
         datosJson = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<JsonElement>>(){}.getType());
          List data = new ArrayList();
         data.addAll(datosJson);
         List data3 = new ArrayList();
        data3 =  SortUtils.sortCollection(data, columns);
                     
       return new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(data3, false);
```

Specifically on the line:

```js
data3 =  SortUtils.sortCollection(data, columns);
```

giving the following errors:

```js
ago 20, 2019 10:15:55 AM ar.com.fdvs.dj.util.MultiPropertyComparator compare
ADVERTENCIA: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'fecha'
ago 20, 2019 10:15:55 AM ar.com.fdvs.dj.util.MultiPropertyComparator compare
ADVERTENCIA: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'velocidad_up'
ago 20, 2019 10:15:55 AM ar.com.fdvs.dj.util.MultiPropertyComparator compare
ADVERTENCIA: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'velocidad_dw'
ago 20, 2019 10:15:55 AM ar.com.fdvs.dj.util.MultiPropertyComparator compare
ADVERTENCIA: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'ppoe_usuario'
ago 20, 2019 10:15:55 AM ar.com.fdvs.dj.util.MultiPropertyComparator compare
ADVERTENCIA: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'ppoe_password'
ago 20, 2019 10:15:55 AM ar.com.fdvs.dj.util.MultiPropertyComparator compare
ADVERTENCIA: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'c'
ago 20, 2019 10:15:55 AM ar.com.fdvs.dj.util.MultiPropertyComparator compare
ADVERTENCIA: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'fecha'
ago 20, 2019 10:15:55 AM ar.com.fdvs.dj.util.MultiPropertyComparator compare
ADVERTENCIA: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'velocidad_up'
ago 20, 2019 10:15:55 AM ar.com.fdvs.dj.util.MultiPropertyComparator compare ....
```

The error is repeated for each of the columns where the data is.

I am very overwhelmed by this problem ... I would like to help me .....

Thanks anyway to everyone, I hope your ideas hopefully find the solution...

The solution already works is that I read my JSON, like JRBeanCollectionDataSource and I must read it as DataSource pass it to jasper .....

Comment: Did you try to use a Collection instead of a List for the type of "data" ?

Comment: de inicio muchas gracias por responder ... a lo que me comentas, para mi la coleccion la tengo en : data3 =  SortUtils.sortCollection(data, columns);.. no se si es lo q dices....

Comment: You need show "C:/tools/2datos-prue.json"

Comment: You need to pass it as a JsonDatasource to jasper report, you are currently using JRBeanCollectionDataSource and it is searching for the methods name (getters) related to you field name.